# Difficulties backporting Linux kernel driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to backport a Linux kernel driver (the PCF85063 RTC, specifically) from the 3.17+ kernel into a 3.14 kernel I'm using, and I'm running into a few issues. I don't have any experience with adding/modifying kernel drivers, so I'm not sure if what I've done so far is correct:

1. I took the [rtc-pcf85063.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-pcf85063.c?v=3.17) file from the newer kernel, and added it to my `drivers/rtc/` directory in the kernel source.
2. I added the following line to `drivers/rtc/Makefile`:

`obj-$(CONFIG_RTC_DRV_PCF85063)  += rtc-pcf85063.o`

3. I added this snippet to `drivers/rtc/Kconfig`

`config CONFIG_RTC_DRV_PCF85063
    tristate "NXP PCF85063"
    help
      If you say yes here, you get support for the NXP PCF85063 RTC.`

From my understanding, that should be all it takes to add driver support for the new RTC. When I execute `make menuconfig`, I can see my new RTC entry under `Device Drivers > Real Time Clock`, labeled as `NXP PCF85063` with the correct help information. So it's clear that the third step above was  successful.

The problem is, when I include this driver (by selecting it in `menuconfig` and saving/exiting) in my kernel build, it doesn't actually get built in. If I deploy the kernel and read `/lib/modules/3.14.17/modules.builtin`, the new driver is nowhere to be found. Also, if I check `drivers/rtc/` after building the kernel, there are object files for every RTC driver included through `menuconfig` **except** the new one; the kernel isn't even compiling the driver.

I found one interesting thing that might give some hint as to what's going on. When I go to `include/config` in the linux source after running `menuconfig`, I have a bunch of directories, some of which correspond to drivers. There's an `rtc` directory, and when I navigate to `include/config/rtc/drv`, there's a header file for every RTC driver included in the build **except** the one I added.

The thing is, the header file corresponding to the new driver **is** in `include/config`; it's hidden away in `include/config/config/rtc/drv`. It looks like `menuconfig` isn't treating the new driver as a regular RTC driver.

I know this is a pretty specific problem, but I was hoping that someone might notice that I'm missing a step or going about this the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: `config CONFIG_RTC_DRV_PCF85063` should be `config RTC_DRV_PCF85063` (without CONFIG_ prefix in configuration option's name)

Comment: Thanks, that completely fixed it. I can't believe I didn't notice the difference between my entry and every other entry in the Kconfig file. Thank you!